# which parts to import in bootstrap 4 customisation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm currently using bootstrap in my application, where I only want to overwrite the primary colour as shown in the scss file below:

```
// Custom.scss

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #243B55
);

// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Aside from this, I just want to use the regular customisations provided by bootstrap. However, since I have included all of bootstrap in the last line, the resulting css file I produce will contain all of the bootstrap code, which will make my application slower. I am thinking of importing just the necessary things to ensure the primary colour is overwritten, and include the rest of the bootstrap library using a CDN (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">`). However, I have not been able to find out which specific things I need to import in my scss file (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/ gives a list but I'm not sure which ones are necessary). If this is a valid strategy to make the application faster, what would I need to import in the scss file at the bottom to ensure that only the primary colour is overwritten?

Comment: Hi @Sabo Boz, which framework or library you are using? or its just plane HTML/CSS project? if possible could you plz upload your code somewhere like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable you need to override is `$primary`. You can place all your variables overrides before importing bootstrap code.

`$theme-colors` will get the overridden value and will generate the code with the default variable value : $primary.

So you can replace your code with:

```
$primary: #243B55;
```